# Xamarin (Android) - Can BaseAdapter return a different data type than Long when overriding GetItemID()?

Tags: android, xamarin, baseadapter

I am inheriting from BaseAdapter and overriding some of the methods. On of them is 
`GetItemID(int iPosition)`.

```
public override long GetItemId(int iPosition)
    {
        return moCustomModels[iPosition].EntityID; //EntityID is a type of Guid
    }
```

The question here is - it does return Long data type and I need it to return Guid - is there anyway to make that happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you are stuck with a long.  That method is used internally by the `AbsListView` to track selection states of items. If you were hoping to have it return a GUID for your own purposes, it would be better to create your own method which returns the GUID.

However if you were using that method specifically to support selection state, then you'll have to come up with some new unique identifier for each position. For additional reading, here's a general C# question which asked a similar question: [Converting GUID to long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670142/converting-guid-to-long).

Comment: Thank you for your response, Jay. I know I can use tags and still pass GUID around but I really prefer to find a more legitimate way of implementing that if there is one. Please feel free to let me know if you have one in mind, sir - I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: Your update is very dangerous.  The position from the click listener is from the adapter.  The adapter's position doesn't map directly to the ListView child's position.  So a ListView's child at index 0 could actually be adapter position 10.  Read here for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6767006/1243753

Comment: Additionally, obtaining your GUID via accessing the view from the ListView is considered bad form.  First off, the View.tag should be used for the adapter's ViewHolder.  Read here for how to do that: http://blog.xamarin.com/creating-highly-performant-smooth-scrolling-android-listviews/

Comment: This gets into MVC behavior.  The ListView is your View.  You shouldn't access the View in order to obtain data.  That's what the model is for.  So the click listener should call into the adapter with the position number asking for the GUID.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation - I see why it is dangerous now.