# Why Does PHP Use objectGUID In Different Order Than Active Directory?

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap, guid

I looked up a distribution list's objectGUID property in ADUC.  However, despite copy/pasting the data directly, my LDAP query wouldn't work.  I queried the same object with different criteria and printed out the fetched GUID and I noticed parts of it are in different order.  Here they are side by side (tabbed apart for readability).

```
34E16D90    BAD1    4ED7    B51A    88C5C4CE7FA2  
 ^----.      \       /
906DE134    D1BA    D74E    B51A    88C5C4CE7FA2
```

As you can see, for each group the pairs themselves are the same, but the order the pairs are arranged are backwards... but for *just the first three groups*.  Other Active Directory tools show the GUID the same as ADUC.  I queried the out-of-order GUID and it works.  Is there an explanation for this?

Comment: `3 < 9`, so the first guid as a whole comes first, regardless of the value of the sub sections.

Comment: @MarcB Sorry, maybe I was unclear.  They both are the GUID for the same object.  The first is how it displays in Active Directory, the second is how it shows when I query the same object in PHP... Unless I'm misunderstanding what you're telling me.

Comment: oh. I see. word-wise reversal in there. I was comparing d1ba->4ed7 and what not.

Comment: I can see how it reads that way.  I'm trying to find a better way to word the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate question (\w Answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7810602/sql-server-guid-sort-algorithm-why

Comment: a little ascii art never hurts.

Comment: @DiceXQ I'll have to look at that answer more when I get home, but wouldn't the endianness just dictate the order of each byte pair and not the order that each pair appears in the group?

Comment: The link implies that only the last 6 bytes are being used by SQL Server to sort GUIDS. Therefor the PHP GUID sorting does not equals the SQLGuid sorting (2 different algoritmes) as far as I can find online :)

Comment: Can you reproduce that behaviour with a console-tool (like ldapsearch) or another third tool (like jXplorer)? That would be interesting whether it's a PHP-issue (which should be fixed then, please open a bug-report on http://bugs.php.net) or an issue with he protocol itself.

Comment: @DiceXQ As far as I read it the link you gave handles sorting of UUIDs. But here it's about displaying UUIDs and even though UUIDs might be stored internally in different formats (little/big-endian) they should always be the same when output (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier#Binary_encoding). So that might be an issue with the ADUC that it shows the UUID in the internal storage format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GUID format is fun. There is a mix endian model that is the 'standard'.  You can parse the Binary data in many different ways. How any particular app represents the GUID as non-Binary is up to the app.

Wikipedia on [GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier) is shockingly interesting.

Comment: Two quotes of note from your source: The first seems to explain the difference in why the two read them, "**Microsoft defines a format which... differs from the UUID standard only in the byte order of the first 3 fields**" and why the first three *fields* (which I mistakenly called groups) behave differently, "**For the first three fields, the most significant digit is on the left. The last two fields are treated as eight separate bytes...**"