# Why do these commands give different values for a Domain Controller GUID?

Tags: powershell, guid, domaincontroller

Evening Folks,

**edited for clarity**

I have to get the Domain Controller GUID for a Certificate Request. I have a script that is provided by our CA that will generate the request and pull the GUID. what I don't understand is why their command *produces a different GUID result from mine*.

Their command

```
([guid]((([directoryservices.directorysearcher] "(distinguishedname=$DistinguishedName)").findall())[0].properties.getenumerator() | ? { $_.name -eq "objectguid"}).value[0]).ToString('N')
```

my command

```
Get-ADDomainController | Select ServerObjectGuid
```

They both provide a GUID that can be translated back to the Domain Controller, but what one is the "right" one?

Comment: The only answer here is if the computer running the script has RSAT or not. If it hasn't then the script provided to you is one way to do it. Otherwise, it's much simpler to just use the AD Module as you're doing.

Comment: The computer has RSAT tools. What I don’t get though is why one provides a different guid than the other. Shouldn’t it be the same, that’s the point of the GUID(unless I’m understanding incorrectly)

Comment: Is it a completely different guid, or does it have the same hex pairs in a different order? See this question for a potential explanation… https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38446421/why-does-php-use-objectguid-in-different-order-than-active-directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ServerObjectGuid` returned by [`Get-ADDomainController`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-addomaincontroller?view=windowsserver2022-ps) is a complete different Guid than the Domain Controller's **computer object** `ObjectGuid`, the `ServerObjectGuid` is the GUID of the object that contains NTDS settings from the Configuration partition of that Domain Controller (these are different objects in Active Directory and of a different **object class** hence different GUIDs).

```bash
$dc = Get-ADDomainController myDC
(Get-ADObject $dc.ServerObjectDN).ObjectGuid -eq $dc.ServerObjectGuid # True
```

If you're looking to compare apples to apples, I would do:

- Using [Active Directory Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/?view=windowsserver2022-ps)

```bash
$dn = 'CN=myDC,OU=Domain Controllers,DC=domain,DC=com'
(Get-ADObject -Filter "distinguishedName -eq '$dn'").ObjectGuid
```

- Using [DirectorySearcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0)

```bash
$dn = 'CN=myDC,OU=Domain Controllers,DC=domain,DC=com'
[guid]::new(([adsisearcher] "(distinguishedName=$dn)").FindOne().Properties['objectGuid'][0])
```

Comment: I’ll give this a look see. Idk why they can’t just put the same ``objectguid`` under the ``get-addomaincontroller`` properties but I appreciate the assistance in clarifying!

Comment: Hah, I can’t take any credit - I was barking up a different tree. I was guessing it might be the same binary guid just serialised into a string in a different order by 2 different tools, which is what the question I linked to was suggesting for its scenario… :-).

Comment: @mclayton fair enough, I misread your comment and also clarified what that GUID actually is.

Comment: @Fitzgery hope my update clarifies what that GUID from `Get-ADDomainController` actually is

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I does clear it up and once again, I appreciate the assistance as always!