# How to sort the GUID or Unique identifer column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to sort the `newID` column by using `ORDER BY`, but when I try to order by the `id` is getting changed each and every time when I execute the query.

I have tired using the `CAST` operator for converting to `VARCHAR` and try to sort it. But it is not working.

```
declare  @temp table
(
    id int identity(1,1),
    newID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
 )
insert into @temp
SELECT NEWID()
insert into @temp
SELECT NEWID()
insert into @temp
SELECT NEWID()
insert into @temp
SELECT NEWID()

select * from @temp 
select * from @temp order by cast(newID as varchar(40)) asc

id  newID
1   9653de71-34c2-4409-bcee-6809e170e197
2   3f3e7ab8-a516-4dd2-a04b-31feeac8fdea
3   1f1d38b8-3c31-4479-ba48-b71ce8525ea3
4   33f1e2b9-f4c3-4e57-9267-ff729a326318

id  newID
3   1f1d38b8-3c31-4479-ba48-b71ce8525ea3
4   33f1e2b9-f4c3-4e57-9267-ff729a326318
2   3f3e7ab8-a516-4dd2-a04b-31feeac8fdea
1   9653de71-34c2-4409-bcee-6809e170e197
```

The second table also I need to get sorted same like the first table when using `ORDER BY` statement.

Comment: There's no `order by statement`. Unless you specify an order with `ORDER BY` the server is free to return the data in any form it likes. If you wanted sequential GUID values use [NEWSEQUENTIALID()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/newsequentialid-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) instead of `NEWID()`. If you want to order the rows by ID, use `ORDER BY ID`

Comment: BTW `IDENTITY` only specifies that the value is autogenerated, it doesn't turn `ID into a primary key nor does it create an index on it

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: The second table i need to sort in ascending, As of now id is 3,4,2,1, But i need it as 1,2,3,4

Comment: Why on earth you are sorting a table on VARCHAR column rather than integer column?

Comment: becuase you cannot order by  newid column, each time it change the order. Pls provide a solution which needs to be in the order 1,2,3,4 always,. You can change varchar or int anything but pls bring the output

Comment: Be aware of how [SQL Server orders guids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7810602/sql-server-guid-sort-algorithm-why). The byte sort order and byte/display order are different.

Comment: if i use  NEWSEQUENTIALID()  instead of newid(), it is throwing error. Please let me know where i need to place query @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: Can you please modify the query and make it sort ascending when i use order by. @DanGuzman

Comment: Am I being stupid or do you just need to `order` based on your `id` column here? `select * from @temp order by id`

Comment: Or are you saying you want the `id` column to simply return the row number of the sorted `newID` values?

Comment: `NEWSEQUENTIALID()` can only be used as the value of a `DEFAULT` constraint, it cannot be used explicitly in an `INSERT` statement. If you change your column to `newId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID()` and your `INSERT`s to `INSERT INTO @temp DEFAULT VALUES`, you'll see sequential IDs. However, I suspect even that is not precisely what you *actually* need. Can you take a step back and explain why you're doing things with GUIDs and why the order is important, beyond this simplified example?

Comment: @DanielStephen, `ORDER BY id` will sort in ascending order but the displayed sequence of byte values does will not match the order SQL Server uses for sorting. Although you could swap bytes for the displayed value such that it appears to match the sort order when read from left to right, that would not show the actual GUID values.

Comment: Basically in our project we are using the GUID for each transaction, sometimes it can be null also. we are using has unique identifier for the column newid. after the inserting into a table, we want to get the same order has it was inserted in the table. But when we do order by for GUID column, it is randomly sorting. I want the same order as it was inserted in the table @JeroenMostert

Comment: That is not possible because such an order does not exist on a logical level. There is an on-disk order of the rows, but there is no way to get that order in T-SQL (nor is it really meaningful, as it could change based on updates and deletes). If you need a deterministic order based on when a row was inserted, you *must* use something like an `IDENTITY` column, a sequence or a time stamp so you can sort by that. A regular GUID is of no use in any case -- there is no chronological relation between GUIDs (at least not the version 4 GUIDs generated by most code).

Comment: Again, just to stress this: the order you get back when you do `SELECT * FROM table` is *undetermined*. It could change, and *does* change, based on such things as whether the server chooses a parallel execution plan. To SQL Server, "insert order" is not a meaningful concept and the physical arrangement of rows is a happenstance.

Comment: Ok fine i can understand, But we can't add a column for identity but let me check whether any column is available for timestamp. anyway thanks a lot @JeroenMostert

Comment: Can you share a sample example for it @DanGuzman

Answer (score 0):

## What I think you are trying to do:

I think you want to return your `newID` values, sorted in ascending order with an incrementing row number in the `id` column.

## What I think you are misunderstanding:

The ID of a row does not need to be in any particular order, it just needs to be unique.  If you are using the incrementing integer value of your `id` column as an identifier elsewhere in your solution, then you do not need to worry about the order.  This is important because if you were to `insert` a new `newID` value that when sorted fell between two existing `newID` values, some of the `id` values would have to change to retain the ordering.  This would break any relationships based on the `id` value.

It is important to note here that the `int identity(1,1)` value automatically increments (not always by 1) for each row *as it is inserted*.  If you `insert` your data 'out of order' then the value will also be 'out of order'.  I think you are misunderstanding what this functionality is for.  In short, it doesn't do what you want it to.

You also *can* order a `uniqueidentifier` column as is.  You will be getting an error because you have called the column `newID`, which is a reserved keyword within SQL Server.  If you want to keep this name (which I suggest you don't), you will need to reference it within square brackets: `order by [newID]`.  Bear in mind that the 'correct' ordering of a `uniqueidentifier` is not the same as the alphabetical ordering of the value you see on the screen, much like how the numeric ordering of `1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12` is different to alphabetically ordering the same values as `1, 10, 11, 12, 2, 3`.

## How to actually get to your desired output:

If on the off chance you really do just want to get the row number of the `newID` value that is in your table, you can do this with the `row_number` windowed function:

```
declare @temp table(id int identity(1,1)
                   ,newID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
                   );
insert into @temp(newID) values
 ('9653de71-34c2-4409-bcee-6809e170e197')
,('3f3e7ab8-a516-4dd2-a04b-31feeac8fdea')
,('1f1d38b8-3c31-4479-ba48-b71ce8525ea3')
,('33f1e2b9-f4c3-4e57-9267-ff729a326318');

-- Showing the int identity, which increments as new rows are added
select *
from @temp
order by [newID];

-- Using the row_number function to generate the id value at runtime
select row_number() over (order by [newID]) as id
      ,[newID]
from @temp
order by [newID];
```

## Outputs

Using `int identity`:

```
+----+--------------------------------------+
| id |                newID                 |
+----+--------------------------------------+
|  2 | 3F3E7AB8-A516-4DD2-A04B-31FEEAC8FDEA |
|  1 | 9653DE71-34C2-4409-BCEE-6809E170E197 |
|  3 | 1F1D38B8-3C31-4479-BA48-B71CE8525EA3 |
|  4 | 33F1E2B9-F4C3-4E57-9267-FF729A326318 |
+----+--------------------------------------+
```

and using `row_number`:

```
+----+--------------------------------------+
| id |                newID                 |
+----+--------------------------------------+
|  1 | 3F3E7AB8-A516-4DD2-A04B-31FEEAC8FDEA |
|  2 | 9653DE71-34C2-4409-BCEE-6809E170E197 |
|  3 | 1F1D38B8-3C31-4479-BA48-B71CE8525EA3 |
|  4 | 33F1E2B9-F4C3-4E57-9267-FF729A326318 |
+----+--------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

NEWSEQUENTIALID()  - This will not generate random sequence id for the GUID. We can use this one instead of Newid().

CREATE TABLE Product_A
(
ID uniqueidentifier default NEWSEQUENTIALID(),
productname int
)

Insert Into Product_A(productname) values(1)
Insert Into Product_A(productname) values(2)
Insert Into Product_A(productname) values(3)
Select * from Product_A

Select * from Product_A               order by ID

I have used like this, but i want to use the newsequentialid in column wise not has default values in table creation.  But it is not possible to use like that. Any suggestion to convert the newid() to newsequentialid because we can sort after the table insertion

Basically in our project we are using the GUID for each transaction, sometimes it can be null also. we are using has unique identifier for the column newid. after the inserting into a table, we want to get the same order has it was inserted in the table. But when we do order by for GUID column, it is randomly sorting. I want the same order as it was inserted in the table